# Opening File using UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl on IPhone Emulator

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hi I am using the following to open the URL and it doesnt work for local addresses

Ie

```
 var url = "http://news.bbc.co.uk/sportacademy/bsp/hi/football/pdf/gerrard.pdf";
 bool result = UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(url));
```

works and loads the browser but

```
 var url = "file:///Users/gerrard.pdf";
 bool result = UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(url));
```

Fails with a message saying the url is not available.

When I do a check using CanOpenURL it says it can open the URL but it doesnt.

Comment: How do you provide the file? Where is it placed?

Comment: I have added the file to the system. It is picked up in the emulator, if I open the url (file:///Users/gerrard.pdf) in Safari on the emulator it loads up

Comment: Hm maybe your app doesn't have the right permissions to access that location then because of the sandboxing. Check out this piece of [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/)

Comment: I have tried copying it to the temp folder and it still doesnt run on the device simulator, but it does work on the browser of the MAC file:///Users/Developers/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F22C6405-0D37-4CFF-A83A-A3E6885B1A71/data/Containers/Data/Application/D0E02894-2FF2-4AD3-A3E0-D8B35A15BF1D/tmp/gerrard.pdf